# How to forcefully remove Google default selected Account in Gmail API?

Tags: android, gmail, gmail-api, google-account

I am trying to remove default selected account from gmail api when logout from app in android.

this is GoogleAccountCredential  function to establish connection of gmail account.

```
GoogleAccountCredential  mCredential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(
                getApplicationContext(), Arrays.asList(AppController.SCOPES))
                .setBackOff(new ExponentialBackOff());
```

Comment: Please, add code which you use to perform login

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Gmail API doesn't Provide And default account select method you can just call this method to select account when required

```
startActivityForResult(
        mCredential.newChooseAccountIntent(),
        REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER);
```

just remember to pass null to `mCredential` when logout

Answer (score 0):

I was tired also, but I have found the solution; If google account is already login after remove default selected account from Gmail API. follow this step...

```
 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
 editor.putString(PREF_ACCOUNT_NAME, null);
 editor.commit();
```

update the value of preferences from particular Key "**PREF_ACCOUNT_NAME**"

~Thanks